# How do I get the price from the body key using NodeJS coinbase pro api

Tags: node.js, coinbase-api

How do I get the price from the body key using NodeJS coinbase pro api?
  I am trying to get the price from the body key using the api command

getProductTicker

Below is what I have so far, but I don't know how to parse the 
 price from the body key.

```
   const CoinbasePro = require('coinbase-pro');
   const publicClient = new CoinbasePro.PublicClient();

        publicClient.getProductTicker('ETH-USD', function(err, obj) {
        console.log('ETH-USD it worked');

        console.log('Start of Entries\n');
        console.log(Object.entries(obj));
        console.log('End of Entries \n');
        console.log('Start of keys\n');
        console.log(Object.keys(obj));
        console.log('End of keys \n');
```

});

Below is the output.  I am trying to get the price from the body key.

```
  _ended: true,
  _callbackCalled: true
}
],
[ 'toJSON', [Function: responseToJSON] ],
[ 'caseless', Caseless { dict: [Object] } ],
[
'body',
'{"trade_id":53067029,"price":"125.24","size":"0.07555643","time":"2019-12- 
 27T17:04:37.429725Z","bid":"125.23","ask":"125.24","volume":"55843.38198278"}'
 ]  
 ]
```

End of Entries

Start of keys

```
 [
 '_readableState',   'readable',
 '_events',          '_eventsCount',
 '_maxListeners',    'socket',
 'connection',       'httpVersionMajor',
 'httpVersionMinor', 'httpVersion',
 'complete',         'headers',
 'rawHeaders',       'trailers',
 'rawTrailers',      'aborted',
 'upgrade',          'url',
 'method',           'statusCode',
 'statusMessage',    'client',
 '_consuming',       '_dumped',
 'req',              'request',
 'toJSON',           'caseless',
 'body'
 ]
```

End of keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the body as it is coming as string. I am not sure if `toJson` method could also be used or not but worth trying. try this.

```
const CoinbasePro = require("coinbase-pro");
const publicClient = new CoinbasePro.PublicClient();

publicClient.getProductTicker("ETH-USD", function(err, obj) {
  const parsedBody = JSON.parse(obj.body);
  const price = parsedBody.price;
});
```